# jstat not found even though we installed java JDK

Tags: rhel, yum, java, jdk

We installed the following RPMs (part of the Java development kit), on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.5:

```
$ rpm -qa | grep jdk
java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.171-8.b10.el7_5.x86_64
java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.171-8.b10.el7_5.x86_64
copy-jdk-configs-3.3-10.el7_5.noarch
```

but we can't find `jstat` which should be on the following path:

```
 /usr/jdk64/jdk1.8.0...../bin/jstat
```

What is wrong here?

Is `jstat` part of the installed RPMs above or do we need another java installation?

```
$ which java
/usr/bin/java
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You haven’t installed the JDK; to install the JDK, which includes `jstat`, you need to install `java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel`.